# Conditional formatting in Excel combining 2 rules?

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to format my dataset (22x12 values) with the 3 color rule, but based on the values of another dataset so that the color can be used as additional information.

Here my example. I want to format my cells in a way, where the colors are displayed according the the color-rule as in column 1 but the values that you see within the colored area are the ones of column 2.

[image]

Column 1 displays %change from a reference. I formatted column 1 with the 3-color rule (lowest=-20, middle=0, highest=+20).

Column 2 gives the originally measured values.

Now I want to substitute the values in column 1 by the ones in column 2, but leave the original "column 1 color formatting" in order to use the coloring as additional information.

I tried the "formula" formatting by marking the colored values in column 1 as `=SUM(values column 2)`, but then the original coloring is gone and the values are still %change.

I read the link Sam suggested, but it is still not working.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Use a formula to apply conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) read this link it will explain how to use conditional formatting

Comment: Kindly edit your question with more details and a screen shot to make us understand how to help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question.  But, I think yes, what you are asking sounds to me like something that is possible.

You need to apply the **range of your conditional format rule to include the cells of "Column 2"**.

If you show us your rules or build a basic example of what you want to achieve, maybe we can give more specific answers.